# A problem from Titu

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

For a positive integer $A$ with decimal representation
$$A=\overline{a_na_{n-1}\dots a_0},$$ we set
$$F(A)=a_n+2a_{n-1}+\dots+2^na_0$$ and consider the sequence $A_0=A,A_1=F(A_0),A_2=F(A_1),\dots$. Then there is a term $A^*$ of this sequence such that $A^*<20$ and $F(A^*)=A^*$.

This is a problem from Titu, I have solved this problem, but I guess $$(AB)^*=(A^*B^*)^*.$$ I don’t know whether this is true, please help me.

Comment: For more information, if A is not equal to 19 or 1-9, then $F(A)<A$.

Comment: Just curious, what or who is Titu?

Comment: Hint: this is essentially the [reversed divisibility by $19$ test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417381/242).

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII Titu Andreescu.

Comment: @BillDubuque I get more understanding about this process, but I still can’t prove this. An obstacle is that not two numbers congruent modulo 19 have the same stable number.

Comment: I elaborated in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are simple counterexamples, e.g. $\,A,B = 2,15\,$ yield $\,3=(AB)^*\!\neq (A^*B^*)^*\!=6$.

As explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4417381/242), $\,A\to A^*\,$ is a common test for divisibility by $19.\,$ It works as a test because $\,19\mid A\iff 19\mid A^*,\,$ but $\,A^*\not\equiv A\pmod{\!19}\,$ in general. Other tests like [casting out nines and elevens](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/16015/242) *do* reduce to congruent numbers $\,A^*\equiv A\,$ so then your equality holds, since then both sides are  $\equiv AB\,$ so being $< m = $ modulus they are equal.

The reason that the $19$ test yields noncongruent numbers is that the reduction step scales by $\:\!2^n.\,$ This preserves divisibility $\,19\mid 2^n A\iff 19\mid A\,$ but it destroys congruence $\,2^n A\not\equiv A\,$ generally.  But the casting out tests do no such scaling, instead reducing using the substitution $\,10^k\equiv (\pm1)^k,\,$ which always preserves congruence.

Comment: Thank you. This is a more satisfactory result.

Comment: @yuan Does this problem arise in the source in the context of a test for divisibility by $19?\,$ Does your questioned equality appear anywhere in the source?