# Differential operators confussion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to solve this PDE:
$$u_t-6uu_x+u_{xxx} = 0\,(1)$$ 
with the Inverse Scattering Method. This method is based on showing that the above equation can be expressed as
$$L_t=LB-BL,\,(2)$$
where $L$ and $B$ are the differential operators:
$$L=-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+u(x)$$
$$B=-4\frac{\partial^3}{\partial x^3}+6u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+3\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}.$$

I have tried to prove that (1) and (2) are equal composing the differential operators $L$ and $B$. However I don't have experience doing this and I got different results.
The way I applied the operators is as if they were just derivatives and by using the chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution, just a suggestion for how to do the calculation. Consider the operator $[L,B]$ acting on some function $\phi$, i.e.

\begin{align} [L,B]\phi & = (-\partial_{xx} + u)(-4\partial_{xxx} + 6u\partial_{x} + 3u_{x})\phi - (-4\partial_{xxx} + 6u\partial_{x} + 3u_{x})(-\partial_{xx} + u)\phi \\
& = \text{a long and messy computation} \\
& = (u_{xxx} - 6uu_{x})\phi\end{align}

All the other terms should cancel and you will have no $\phi_{x}$, $\phi_{xx}$ or $\phi_{xxx}$ in your answer. Notice that the coefficients in front of the $\phi$ term are just the time-independent part of the KdV.

Answer (score 1):

The keyword is *Operator Calculus* or alternatively *Operational Calculus*.
Here is an introductory [(PDF) document](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2004/uitboek.pdf) .
Other references are easily found on the internet, such as
[Fractional Calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus) (Wikipedia),
[What is operator calculus?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/10160/what-is-operator-calculus) (MSE).
The key formula you should IMHO use is not the chain rule [ it's rather derived from $(uv)' = u'v + uv'$ ] :
$$
   \frac{d}{dx} f = f \frac{d}{dx} + \frac{df}{dx}
$$
Mind that differentiation and multiplying with a function *do not commute* with Operator Calculus. But, in my experience, that's almost the only thing to take care of.

Comment: What has to do fractional calculus with this?